# SQLServer AlwaysOn Availability Groups in 2014 and 2016

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, availability-groups, high-availability

We're designing a new, HA database cluster to support two of our vendor software applications; both applications are mission critical so we are trying to make sure we get this right.

One vendor will support SQLServer 2016 but the other is only validated against 2014. The second vendor is not preventing us from using 2016 but, I know customer support will be an issue down the road (it'll be the thing they blame any time anything goes wrong...)

Both applications are pretty vanilla in terms of how they use the database.

I'd like to know whether there are compelling enough reasons to use 2016 that I would risk the support issues with my second vendor. Stability and operational support issues vs. 2014 are my biggest concerns.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of reasons to upgrade to 2016 and even possibly 2017, however if a vendor will not support you on those versions, then the benefits of 2016 and 2017 are moot. It is less risky to stay with a supported version than to take on the benefits of what 2016 and 2017 will bring you.